# libcurl kubuntu 11.04

Tags: version, libcurl, ubuntu, natty

I'm trying to compile some application on my kubuntu (no package is available) and while configuring the app it prints out this error:

```
checking for curl-config... no
checking whether libcurl is usable... no
configure: error: Missing required libcurl >= 7.10.1
```

So my first question is - how can I check what version of libcurl I have? I listed libcurl libraries in /usr/lib:

```
$ ls /usr/lib/libcurl*
/usr/lib/libcurl-gnutls.so.3  /usr/lib/libcurl-gnutls.so.4  
/usr/lib/libcurl-gnutls.so.4.2.0  /usr/lib/libcurl.so.3  
/usr/lib/libcurl.so.4  /usr/lib/libcurl.so.4.2.0
```

So I thaught I have only version 4 of libcurl. I begun searching for newer version of libcurl, but was not able to find it neither in package manager nor curl homepage.

So could anyone advice me, how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need a libcurl devel package.

You can select among different ones depending on what underlying SSL lib you prefer:

- libcurl4-gnutls-dev - Development files and documentation for libcurl (GnuTLS)
- libcurl4-nss-dev - Development files and documentation for libcurl (NSS)
- libcurl4-openssl-dev - Development files and documentation for libcurl (OpenSSL)

Comment: Which one would you suggest if I'm unsure about my preferred underlying SSL lib?

Comment: The openssl one is probably the most commonly used and tested.